# Can a class with a list/array be passed in an UseInMemoryDatabase?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm creating a dumb database using `UseInMemoryDatabase` in .net, but I cannot pass a list/array in the class that I trying to put in the memory.

```
public class Products
{
    [Key]
    public long productId { get; set; }
    public string productName { get; set; }
    public double productPrice { get; set; }
    public string productDescription { get; set; }
    public string[] category{ get; set; }

    public Products(long productId, string productName, double productPrice, string productDescription, string[] category)
    {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

Then I am trying to add this class in memory.

```
services.AddDbContext<ProductContext>(opts => opts.UseInMemoryDatabase("Products"));
```

But when I call the context and the class, I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No suitable constructor found for entity type 'Products'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'category' in 'Products(long productId, string productName, double productPrice, string productDescription, string[] category)'.'

I'm trying to know if it is something possible?

Comment: No it's not possible. And if it was, what would you gain by that? You'd have a test database that is capable of storing object you can't store in a "real" database. In-memory database may be useful for easily getting and storing test objects, but the data access code should always be tested against the production database brand.

Comment: Postgres has array types so this would be a valid model.